# Why $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2n}+o(\frac1n))^n= e^{-\frac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}}$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

> Why is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\Big(1-\frac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2n}+o(\frac1n)\Big)^n=\large e^{-\frac{\sigma^2\xi^2}{2}}$ ?

Why has $o(\frac{1}{n})$ no effect on the term ? Can I also conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\Big(1+o(\frac1n)\Big)^n=1$ ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374747/if-z-n-to-z-then-1z-n-nn-to-ez

Comment: The answer to your second question is "yes". Just take $\sigma^2=0$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/821399/5531

Comment: @AntonioVargas: useful link, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at 
$$
\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n^{1+ \epsilon}}\bigg)^n = \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n^{1 +\epsilon} } \bigg)^{n^{1+ \epsilon -\epsilon}} = \bigg( 1+\frac{1}{n^{1 +\epsilon} } \bigg)^{n^{1+ \epsilon} \cdot n^{-\epsilon}} \leq e^{n^{-\epsilon}} \to_n 1
$$

EDIT: another way: the lower bound is due to Bernoulli inequality. Since $n > 0$
$$
(1+ o(\frac{1}{n})^n \geq (1+n o(\frac{1}{n})) \to_n 1
$$
upper bound: 
$$
(1+o(\frac{1}{n}))^n \leq e^{n o(\frac{1}{n})} \to_n 1
$$
this is due to $n o(\frac{1}{n}) \to_n 0$.

Comment: Awesome. I think this is sufficient.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: but is any function, which is $o(\frac1n)$, of the form $\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ ?

Comment: take the limit: $ \frac{\frac{1}{n^{1 + \epsilon}}}{\frac{1}{n}}$. What do you get?

Comment: here of course $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small. Think of the smallest real number possible and take $\epsilon$ less than it.

Comment: You showed the converse

Comment: What do you mean? The limit is $\frac{1}{n^ \epsilon} \to 0$, hence $\frac{1}{n^{1 + \epsilon}} = o(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: I asked: If you have a function $f$ such that, $f=o(\frac1n)$ is $f$ necessarily of the form $\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ for some $\epsilon$, or can $f$ also be for example $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ (there might be better examples). How do you justify your answer then ?

Comment: plese see the edit