# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1+\frac xn-o(\frac 1n))^n=e^x$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, exponential-function

We know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1+\frac xn)^n=e^x$.
How to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1+\frac xn-o(\frac 1n))^n=e^x$?

Attempt of the proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ $\exists n_0$ such that $\forall n\ge n_0$ $|o(\frac 1n)|<\epsilon\frac 1n$ and $|n*o(\frac 1n)|<\epsilon$.

Thus 
$(1+\frac{x+\epsilon}{n})^n>(1+\frac xn-o(\frac 1n))^n>(1+\frac{x-\epsilon}{n})^n$.

So $e^x*e^\epsilon \ge \lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1+\frac xn-o(\frac 1n))^n \ge \frac{e^x}{e^\epsilon}$ $\forall \epsilon>0$.

Say $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(1+\frac xn-o(\frac 1n))^n=y$, it can not be that $y<e^x$, because if it is so, then $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $e^\epsilon y<e^x$ and the second inequality above is violated. By the similar talking $y>e^x$ is impossible.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Could you say that as $n\to\infty$ then $O(\frac{1}{n})\to0$ and therefore that term becomes insignificant as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821399/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-the-limit-with-little-o)

Comment: The problem is that even though $O(\frac{1}{n}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ who knows what it does when it's put into an expression where the exponent itself approaches infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = o(\frac{1}{n})$. Let $0 < \varepsilon < e^x$. Choose an $r > 0$ such that $e^{x - r} > e^x - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $e^{x + r} < e^x + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} na_n = 0$, there exists an $N_1\in \Bbb N$ such that $|na_n| < r$ for all $n\ge N_1$. Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{x - r}{n})^n = e^{x - r}$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac{x + r}{n})^n = e^{x + r}$, there exist $N_2, N_3\in \Bbb N$ such that $(1 + \frac{x-r}{n})^n > e^{x - r} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\ge N_3$ and $(1 + \frac{x + r}{n})^n < e^{x + r} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\ge N_2$. Let $N = \max\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$. If $n\ge N$, then $$\left(1 + \frac{x}{n} - a_n\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac{x - na_n}{n}\right)^n > \left(1 + \frac{x - r}{n}\right)^n > e^{x - r} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2} > e^x - \varepsilon$$ and $$\left(1 + \frac{x}{n} - a_n\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac{x - na_n}{n}\right)^n < \left(1 + \frac{x + r}{n}\right)^n < e^{x + r} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} < e^x + \varepsilon.$$ Thus $$\left\lvert \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} - a_n \right)^n - e^x\right\rvert < \varepsilon \quad \text{if $n\ge N$.}$$ Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} - o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n = e^x.$$

Comment: Thanks for the proof, only one comment, I would not right $r \in (0,x)$, because firstly it could be that $x<0$ and secondly the condition $r>0$ is just enough, is not it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. More specifically, $r$ is chosen such that $$0 < r < \min\left\{-\log\left(1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2e^x}\right), \log\left(1 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2e^x}\right)\right\}$$

Comment: thank you for the answer, I marked it as accepted. One small comment, do you really need $\epsilon > e_x$, would not it suffice to say $\epsilon >0$? BTW what do you think about the proof I proposed in my question above?

Comment: @SergeyZykov yes I needed $\varepsilon > e^x$ so that $\log(1 - \varepsilon\cdot e^{-x}/2)$ makes sense. In your proof, you didn't show that $\lim(1 + x/n - o(1/n))^n$ exists; you assumed that the limit exists.